# No puedo configurar bootstrap en Angular 13 para que obtenga el js y el css desde la carpeta assets configurandolo en angular.json

Tags: javascript, css, json, angular, angularjs

Hola estoy haciendo un curso de Angular que compre y estoy intentando que los archivos de bootstrap que me he descargado para tener bootsrap en local tire de las carpetas src/assets/css y  src/assets/js, los archivos de bootstrap tienen todos los permisos.

```
Gracias a toda la comunidad de antemano ;)
```

La estructura es esta:
[image: La estructura es esta:]

He probado a las rutas de los js y css las siguientes rutas:
js/bootstrap.min.js
src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js

Lo que he aprendido es que en el archivo de configuración angular.json en el atributo script y styles se puede poner la ruta de los css y js para no tener las etiquetas script en el index.html y los he puesto así:

[image: .]
El index.html lo he dejado vacío
[image: .]

El error al ejecutar     `ng serve -o es` este:
[image: .]

Genera un log:

[image: .]
Cuando accedo a la pagina se ve así
[image: .]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe ser `src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.js`. Nota que la ruta viene desde `src/..`, lo mismo para los scripts.

## Edición.

No es necesario que agregues tu css en `styles`.  `src/assets` lo hará por ti directamente:

Tu `angular.json` debería verse así:

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets" //Aqui va tu css. 
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Con esto bastaría para que desde el index hagas lo siguiente:

```
<link href="assets/css/boostrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar @Legna  eso lo probe antes de preguntar pero luego probe dos o tres cosas mas y lo termine dejando mal sin darme cuenta, cuando lo pongo bien como dices al ejecutar el comando `ng serve -o` da fallo al compilar y me dice Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/antoniojesusponcevela/curso/angular/src/assets' in '/Users/antoniojesusponcevel
a/curso/angular'
Me he metido en la carpeta y esta en esa en curso/angular 
En el servidor aparece cannot get

Comment: Hola!, no entiendo muy tu comentario. Te funcionó o sigue dando un error?

Comment: si sigue dando error al ejecutar ng serve -o no termina de compilar  y me sale un log de error que me meto en ese log y pone 
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/antoniojesusponcevela/curso/angular/src/assets' in '/Users/antoniojesusponcevel a/curso/angular'

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el mensaje completo de error en texto? Para ver si hay algo que se me esté escapando.

Comment: No ocupas definir dos veces assets. Revisa la edición a mi respuesta.